# How to calculate multiple sum in an object grouping by a property in Java8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm doing some calculations with some data. The object has several numeric properties. I have achieved calculating grouping by the type on one property. But the need is to calculate on each numeric value. So, is there any method to solve this problem?

```
Person p1 = new Person("p1","type1",18,3);
Person p2 = new Person("p2","type2",10,6);
Person p3 = new Person("p3","type1",5,8);

List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(p1);
personList.add(p2);
personList.add(p3);

Map<String, Integer> collect = 
        personList.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                Person::getType,Collectors.summingInt(Person::getAge)
            )
        );
```

I expect the sum of each property and a single result map. The value of the map is a map/array/list.
For example:

```
type1 [23,11]
type2 [10,6]
```

Comment: An important part for you would be to define the **type** of such a map.

Comment: What is the name of the 2nd property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments as well, defining the type of your output matters here. To add a gist of how you can plan to do it, you can use `Collectors.toMap` with custom `mergeFunction` as :

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Person> collect = personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getType, a -> a, (p1, p2) ->
                new Person(p1.getX(), p1.getType(),
                        p1.getAge() + p2.getAge(),
                        p1.getCode() + p2.getCode()))); // named the other attribute 'code'
```

Now, against every `type` you have a `Person` object with *integer values summed.*